# on the way to home or on the way of home or on the way home?

Tags: sentence-construction

Consider:

1. > She was nervous on the way of home.
2. > She was nervous on the way to home.
3. > She was nervous on the way home. (I prefer this one since it is more compact)

Are the three sentences are grammatically correct?
If the answer is yes, is there any differences?
Regards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only the third one is correct and idiomatic:

> She was nervous on the way home.

"**Home**" is here an ***adverb*** with the meaning "*at or to ​one's ​house or the ​place where one ​lives*".  Other uses can be "*I am home*" (although it is perfectly fine if you say "I am ***at*** home", in which case "*home*" is a ***noun***)

Comment: Are you saying the others are grammatically wrong ? I have searched all of the three sentences with double quotation mark and have obtained considerable results.

Comment: Well, (2) is not "wrong" since "home" as a noun is allowed to be used in such a context and with the preporsion "to", but it's rather awkward and not idiomatic.  (1) is plain wrong.  (3) is correct and idiomatic.

Comment: So , Please answer more carefully, I am going to down vote this quick answer!, Sorry

Comment: Consider an Edit

Comment: It is nice of you

Comment: +1 for a useful answer.  Note that in post-Jespersen grammar, *home* is analyzed as an intransitive preposition.

Comment: @VictorBazarov See here dear vici : 
https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22on+the+way+to+home%22&start=10

Comment: @Cardinal *on the way home* is a thousand times more common than *on the way to home*.  See Google Ngram Viewer or your corpus of choice: https://goo.gl/bqUDWf

Comment: @snailboat does that mean it is grammatically wrong ? however, thabks for the charts

Comment: @snailboat See here, too: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22on+the+way+of+home%22&start=20

Comment: I past wrong links about the of and to, however, I am not convinced they are grammatically wrong or a plain wrong

Comment: @Cardinal In the majority of web pages found by the first search ("way to home") were either variations on "way to home sweet home" or questions whether it's OK, or "home" was an adjective ("way to home plate").  In the second search only 62 results, and most of them are simply ungrammatical.

Comment: @Cardinal, you didn't post wrong links, SE contracts those, they work fine.

Comment: Ok, that is fine